# displaying funny characters after substr() text with accent marks

Tags: php

I am using substr() function to cut strings. It worked ok with normal string but in case of string with accent marks, it displayed funny characters just before the cut like this:

Here is the code:

```
$rawtitle ="Tin đăng của giangvy1011 tin của dtdd";
$title = substr($rawtitle,0,36).'...';
echo $title;
```

Here is the result i got for the echo:

[image]

Is there any way around this or different function to archieve this? Many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[substr](http://php.net/manual/it/function.substr.php) is not multibyte safe. The character `ủ` is represented by more than a byte. With substr you cut these byte sequences and you corrupt the string.

You need to use [mb_substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) instead.